# KSH: Variables containing double quotes

Tags: linux, string, shell, echo, ksh

I have a string called STRING1 that could contain double quotes.

I am echoing the string through sed to pull out puntuation then sending to array to count certain words. The problem is I cannot echo variables through double quotes to sed.

I am crawling our filesystems looking for files that use FTP commands.
I grep each file for "FTP"

```
STRING1=`grep -i ftp $filename`
```

If you echo $STRING1 this is the output (just one example)

```
myserver> echo "Your file `basename $1` is too large to e-mail. You must ftp the file to BMC tech support. \c"
    echo "Then, ftp it to ftp.bmc.com with the user name 'anonymous.' \c"
    echo "When the ftp is successful, notify technical support by phone (800-537-1813) or by e-mail (support@bmc.com.)"
```

Then I have this code

```
STRING2=`echo $STRING1|sed 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/ /g'`
```

I have tried double quoting $STRING1 like

```
STRING2=`echo "$STRING1"|sed 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/ /g'`
```

But that does not work.
Single Qoutes, just sends $STRING1 as the string to sed...so that did not work.

What else can I do here?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with how you're setting `STRING1` to begin with. If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, you need to write:

```
STRING1="Your file `basename $1` is too large to e-mail. You must ftp the file to BMC tech support. \c
Then, ftp it to ftp.bmc.com with the user name 'anonymous.' \c
When the ftp is successful, notify technical support by phone (800-537-1813) or by e-mail (support@bmc.com.)"
```

Then you can write:

```
STRING2=`echo "$STRING1"|sed 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/ /g'`
```

Comment: I am not manually creating STRING1. STRING1 is created by grep. STRING1=`grep -i ftp $filename`  How can i put "" around that?

Comment: @nitrobass24: Sorry, I don't understand what you're doing. Can you edit your question to include (1) how you're setting `STRING1` and (2) the output you get when you type `echo "$STRING"`?

Comment: @nitrobass24: Then your second version -- the one with the double-quotes -- works just fine for me. It sets `$STRING2` to be just the same as `$STRING1`, except that all characters except letters, digits, and newlines are replaced with spaces. Are you seeing something different?

Comment: The question is still not clear, but double quotes is what you should be using when echoing a variable. Your problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
/home/user1> S1='"double         quotes"'
/home/user1> echo "$S1"
"double         quotes"

/home/user1> S2=`echo "$S1"|sed 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/ /g'` 
/home/user1> echo "$S2"
 double         quotes
```